# Exchanging header and footer in html doc

Tags: html

I am new to web development and one question I was asked in interview that

In html page what will happen if we define header at bottom and footer at top. Will they exchange their position or not? I tried searching it but didn't got any better explanation. Please help.

Comment: you are talking about <header> tag at bottom and <footer> tag at top. right?

Comment: yes. In that case how content will appear on page. Means if header is defined at bottom so will its content will appear at bottom or at top? and why

Comment: <header> and <footer> are tags.  That's about it, they don't define positions.

Comment: Try it! Make 2 html pages and swap the header and footer. Then experiment with what you can do with CSS… :)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it all depends on where you define the tags. What I mean by this is that the display will follow the structure of your HTML code. **For example, if you define your header at the bottom and the footer at the top, the display will follow your structure and you will see your header at the bottom and the footer at the top.**